# LM3886 full amp reduces hi freqs

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, music, preamp

I've bought [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM3886-LME49720-UPC1237-speaker-protection-68W-68W-8ohm-stereo-amplifier-kit-WLX-/151331838843?pt=US_Amplifier_Parts_Components&hash=item233c149b7b) kit and successfully assembled it.
I use 23.4-0.23.4 V power source and two ELZET 10000uF caps.

So, after I connected my speakers (by the way it is Amphithon [(Амфитон) 25АС-027](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tU9cxHnhThA) 4 Ohm, it is USSR speakers, very powerful and have isodynamic tweeter) I noticed there a lot of bass (and not enough hi-freqs), my windows started vibrating at 10% volume.

I tried to use EQ and lower low freqs, but it didn't helped much.
So, I decieded to investigate a bit how it works, I removed the OPAMP and installed jumpers to pass input signal bypassing OPAMP, so I completely get rid of OPAMP impact actually. The sound became a bit hush but still bassy. After that I decieded to investigate the preamp schematics, I used multimeter and created a wiring diagram, Here it is.

[image: pre-amp schematics]

After removing highlighted resistor the sound became clear and crisp.

So, my question is why do I need that resistor? What other components can affect sound? Is it Ok to remove highlighted resistor? Why these components needed, I can't find that type of apllication in datasheet...

Comment: What value(s) are the two caps on the bottom supposed to be?

Comment: Are you asking about SMD caps? They are should be 100pF, but that they actually are I do not know since there is no info on them. I'll try to find needed caps in my local store and will replace these just to ensure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1kohm you removed and presumably shorted would have had a low pass 3dB frequency point (with the 100pF capacitor) of about 1.5MHz - way above audio so shorting it out should have no effect, but there's no guarantee that the correct resistor was fitted or that the 100pF isn't something like 10nF. A 10nF would give a 15 kHz cut-off and a 22nF would be about 7 kHz so maybe this info can help you track down the problem a bit more.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You really helped me to solve the issue. I just replaced two SMD caps that should be 100pF each (but they are not marked) with 100pF ceramic disc capacitors. It looks ugly but souns pretty good. Will replace on SMDs later. After the replace I have got powerfull and clear sound. Thanks again!